# WebService method always receives null in request

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I have the web service running on JBoss with method search.

```
@WebService(serviceName = "MyService", portName = "MyServicePort", name = "MyService", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/MyService", wsdlLocation = "wsdl/myService.wsdl")
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class MyWebServiceBean extends MyService {
    @Override
    @WebMethod(operationName="Search")
    @WebResult(name = "AvailRS")
    public AvailRS search(@WebParam(name = "AvailRQ") AvailRQ request) {
        return super.search(request);
    }
}
```

myService.wsdl:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<definitions
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/MyService"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:ans="http://www.example.org/example"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/MyService" name="MyService">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="wsdl/xsd/AvailRQ.xsd"
                namespace="http://www.example.org/example">
            </xsd:import>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="wsdl/xsd/AvailRS.xsd"
                namespace="http://www.example.org/example">
            </xsd:import>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="SearchRequest">
        <part name="searchRequest" element="ans:AvailRQ"/>
    </message>
    <message name="SearchResponse">
        <part name="searchResponse" element="ans:AvailRS"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="MyService">
        <operation name="Search">
            <input message="tns:SearchRequest"/>
            <output message="tns:SearchResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="MyServicePortBinding" type="tns:MyService">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
            style="document" />
        <operation name="Search">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="MyService">
        <port name="MyServicePort" binding="tns:MyServicePortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ws/MyService" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Imported xsd are well-styled and don't contain any errors.
The problem: when I send a request to my service, I always gets AvailRQ (WebParam) == null.
I've tried generated cliend and SOAP UI.
There're no problems with marshalling/unmarshalling request.
Just a NullPointer :(

Comment: What is in the `wsdl/xsd/AvailRS.xsd` and `wsdl/xsd/AvailRQ.xsd` ?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mismatch between the annotation in the method and what the name you have in the WSDL for the name of the field in the input message:

```
<portType name="MyService">
    <operation name="Search">
        <input message="tns:SearchRequest"/>
        ... 
   </operation>
</portType>
<message name="SearchRequest">
    <part name="searchRequest" element="ans:AvailRQ"/>
</message>
```

I would attempt to look at the actual HTTP traffic sent across the wire to see what the name of the field in the SOAP message is for sure.

Comment: I've tried
`@WebParam(name = "searchRequest")` and
`@WebParam(name = "SearchRequest")`, but it still doesn't work.